# TypeORM: Fetching foreign key value from typeorm-model-generator generated entity

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I have problem fetching the foreign key when using generated typeorm entitys from typeorm-model-generator.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeorm-model-generator

The generated entity

```
@ManyToOne(() => Accountplan, (accountplan) => accountplan.companies)
@JoinColumn([{ name: "defaultaccountplan", referencedColumnName: "id" }])
defaultaccountplan: Accountplan;
```

When trying to fetch Accountplan id (foreign key) from table Company both company.defaultaccountplan.id and company.defaultaccountplan returns undefined? Company.id works fine.

Code:

```
const company = await getRepository(Company).findOne({
      where: {
        orgid: id,
      },
});
console.log(company.id);
console.log(company.defaultaccountplan.id);
```

---

If I add Column defaultaccountplan to entity I can use company.defaultaccountplan to get id

```
 @Column("integer", { name: "defaultaccountplan", nullable: true })
  defaultaccountplan: number | null;
```

Do I need the column defaultaccountplan or should I do the query differently?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the relation to the query and you will get the complete object.

```
const company = await getRepository(Company).findOne({
      where: {
        orgid: id,
      },
      relations: ['defaultaccountplan']
});
```